# A connected linearly ordered set is a linear continuum

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, connectedness

> Let $X$ be a linearly ordered set in the order topology which is connected. Show that $X$ is a linear continuum.

- A [*linear continuum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_continuum) is a linearly ordered set $X$ with more than one element that is densely ordered (*i.e.*, between any two members there is another), and has the least upper bound property (*i.e.*, every nonempty subset with an upper bound has a least upper bound)

I know that $X$ has the intermediate value property because it is connected, but I don't know why it satisfies the least upper bound property.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If $A$ is non-empty and has an upper bound $u$ but no least upper bound, consider the sets

$$A_1 = \{ x \in X \mid \exists y(x) \in A: x \le y(x) \}$$
and 
$$A_2 = X \setminus A_1 = \{ x \in X \mid \forall y \in A: x > y \}$$

As $A \subset A_1$, it is non-empty. As $u$ cannot be in $A$ (as an upper bound for $A$ that is in $A$ is a maximum which is also a least upper bound for $A$), $u > y$ for all $u \in A$, so $u \in A_2$, so $A_2$ is non-empty as well.

Both sets are disjoint, and cover $X$ by definition.

$A_1$ is open, as for all $x \in A_1$, $x \in (\leftarrow, y(x)) \subset A_1$, if indeed $x < y(x)$. If $x = y(x) \in A$, we know that some $x' \in A$ must exist with $x' > x$, as otherwise $x = \max(A) = \sup(A)$ which cannot be. Then $x \in (\leftarrow, x') \subset A_1$ as well.

$A_2$ is open, because if $x \in A_2$, $x$ is an upper bound for $A$, but it cannot be the smallest such (as $A$ has no smallest upper bound by assumption!), so there is a smaller upper bound $z$ for $A$ and clearly $x \in (z, \rightarrow) \subset A_2$.

This contradicts connectedness of $X$.

Comment: Sorry for stupid question, but what does $(\leftarrow, y(x))$ stand for? Does it stand for $(b, y(x))$, here $b$ is the smallest element in $X$? If so, why $x \in (\leftarrow, y(x))$, because $x$ can be equal to $y(x)$

Comment: $(\leftarrow,y) = \{x \in X: x < y \}$

Comment: Yeah, in that case, I don't understand why $x \in (\leftarrow, y(x))$, because x can be equal to $y(x)$. I think $A_1$ should be $\{x \in X | \exists y(x) \in A: x \lt y(x)\}$

Comment: Edited the answer to make it more complete. It needed one extra argument.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that it doesn't satisfy the least upper bound property for a proper subset that has an upper bound. Take such a subset set that doesn't satisfy the least upper bound property, and the complement of the subset, and show that they are both open.

Comment: This almost works, but you have to "convexify" the set. See my answer.