# Let X be a non-degenerate ordered set and give X the order topology. If X is connected, then X is a linear continuum.

Tags: general-topology

Let X be a non-degenerate ordered set and give X the order topology. If X is connected, then X is a linear continuum.

This is what I showed. Kindly check and let me know whether its correct or wrong.

[image]

Need help in this.

Comment: (oo,y) is always empty.

Comment: why? n how does this relate to this theorem?

Comment: Read [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/753623/4280) for a solution.

Comment: Some subset is (maybe) connected so $X$ is disconnected? Nonsense, I say.

Comment: n is not in the theorem, @Math_Is_Fun

Comment: @WilliamElliot I meant "and" as n. lolz :P ;D

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun.  You did not say "and".  You said "n". Futhermore "lolz:P:D" is meaningless.  I recommend that you use English.

Comment: ok sorry, I will use that next time. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x,y)$ is empty for some $x <y$ in $X$, then $\{(-\infty, y), (x, +\infty)\}$
is a partition of $X$ into non-empty (!) open sets, so $X$ is disconnected.

As to the sup property, I showed that [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/753806/4280), it's a bit more subtle than you seem to think.

Comment: gotcha, thanks for helping me on this.